# Flex 4 ColorPicker not editable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

I've got an application with several ColorPickers in them - they're just used as-is, no data provider-derived colours or anything - with editable = true. However, the textfield used to display/input the hex code for the selected colour is greyed out and uneditable. I can't find any help for this, only a plethora of tutorials telling me to set editable as true, which obviously doesn't work.

Have also tried binding to data array of colours, but this does nothing except stop the field from being greyed out (though no text appears or can be edited inside it).

Does anyone know how I can stop this happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears a dodgy font (set as the default for the entire application) was not showing up in the hex panel - forcing it to Arial did the trick. Probably more a result of the crazy set of fonts we have to use than anything but worth doing if anyone else gets a problem like this!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me just fine in Flex 3.6A and 4.6.0. Is there maybe something else your doing that is non standard? What theme are you using? Can you produce a test case that demonstrates the issue? (PS: sorry, I can't add comments yet)

Comment: With a blank case I can get it to work without issue, I believe there's some issue with stylesheets affecting it - given the size of the project, it would not be sensible to post anything about it, I'm just going to have to strip it down, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with Flex 4.10.0 (can edit the text field):

```
<mx:ColorPicker id="_bgPicker" showTextField="true" />
```